# How does this permutation generator work?

Tags: permutation, pascal, bit-shift

I've been given a tip the following code will work, and it does, however I am using it in a little research project and need to thoroughly understand what exactly is the principle behind it.

```
for i:=0 to (PNum-1) do begin
for j:=0 to (SMax-1) do begin
write(f, ((i shr j) and 1));
end;
writeln(f);
end;
```

Basically, it generates all PNum variations of SMax-symbol long string containing 0 and 1. My question is, what does `((i shr j) and 1)` (shr being right bit shift in Pascal) do?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't see anything permutation related here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression

```
((i shr j) and 1)
```

extracts the `j`-th bit from the binary representation of `i´ (bits counting from zero from the right).

Example:

```
i = 23; j = 3;

bin[23] = 10111    
bin[23 shr 3] = 10111 shr 3 = 10
bin[23 shr 3] and 1 = 10 and 1 = 0
```

Note: the algorithm builds all *combinations* of `[0,1]` if `PNum = 2^SMax` and not all *permutations*.

Comment: Cheers. You must be correct, these are indeed combinations, confused my terminology there. However, why does this allow us to generate strings, say, like 0000000
1000000
0100000
1100000
0010000
1010000
0110000
1110000
0001000 an so forth with i=2^6 and j=6?

Comment: @user1136946 Because the binary representation consists of all combinations of zero and one (just look at how the numbers start: 000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111, i.e. all combinations of zero and one of length three). Note that your example is just the reverse of these binary strings.